# How do I programatically identify forked github repos?

Tags: github, github-api

Using the github API, how can I determine if a repo has been forked from another repo?  An example using `gh api` would be ideal.

Context: I would like to apply some different automated processing to my github repos depending on whether or not they have been forked from another repo.

Comment: uhm from https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-repository i can see an attribute `fork`...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Thanks, but that doesn't work for private repos.  That's why I think I need to use the API (hopefully via `gh`).

Comment: And if you're looking for a private clone of a public repo, GitHub doesn't gister these as a fork. Technically they may be, but logically GitHub sees them as 2 separate repos. In that case inspecting the root commit may give you an indication they share the same history. But a fork van diverge or rewrite history of it's upstream, so that's no guarantee either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access your private repositories, use `gh login` to authenticate yourself. Once authenticated, you will see your private repositories  and any other resources to which your account has access.

The `repos/` response contains a `.fork` indicator.

```sh
echo ghp_YOUR_TOKEN | gh auth login --with-token

gh api --method=GET repos/<user>/<repo> --jq ".fork"
false/true
```